# How to access , change and print a variable by its memory adress in c?

Tags: c, variables, memory, memory-address

let's say that i have an integer variable (var) ,and it's memory adress is 1234f , but i dont know the name of this variable and i want to see what value does the memory adress 1234f have , and print it out or change it . is there any possible ways to do this in c ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to access , change and print a variable by its memory address in c?

Assuming the address value is valid:

First create a `int *`.

```
int *var_pointer = (int *) 0x1234f;
printf("%d\n", *var_pointer);
*var_pointer = 42;
printf("%d\n", *var_pointer);
```

If address is not valid, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

Comment: why did you do (int *) 1234f; instead of int *var_pointer = (int *) 1234f;

Comment: `1234f` has to be `0x1234f`

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Yes.  Post amended.

Comment: This is implementation defined. From C Standard: *An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.)*

Comment: @N.Dogac The conversion from `int` to `int *` is _mplementation defined_ as per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712033/how-to-access-change-and-print-a-variable-by-its-memory-adress-in-c/63712118?noredirect=1#comment112668345_63712118).  The dereferencing as in `*var_pointer`  can incur UB due to misalignment, etc.